# Is a JavaScript function call a LeftHandSideExpression, thus an ExpressionStatement?

Tags: javascript, bnf, function-call, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to prove that a simple function call such as

```
window.alert();
```

is valid EcmaScript 2016 (7th Edition) grammar. Working backward, with the expectation this is an *ExpressionStatement*, I see that it fits the pattern *MemberExpression Arguments* which is a *CallExpression*. And, section **12.3** defines *LeftHandSideExpression* as possibly a *CallExpression*. Now, my problem is that section **12.15** *AssignmentExpression* seems to require that  *LeftHandSideExpression* be followed by either an *AssignmentExpression* or an *AssignmentOperator* and *AssignmentExpression* cannot be **;**

I'm probably missing something simple. Direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

An [*AssignmentExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression) does not necessarily need to be an assignment, it only means "an assignment could stand here". It can also consist of solely a *ConditionalExpression*. And now we need to go down the whole chain of associativity rules:
A [*ConditionalExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-ConditionalExpression) can contain a ternary operator or consist solely of a *LogicalORExpression*. A [*LogicalORExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-LogicalORExpression) can contain an `||` operator or consist solely of a *LogicalANDExpression*. And so on: A [*LogicalANDExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-LogicalANDExpression) can consist solely of a [*BitwiseORExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-BitwiseORExpression) which can consist of solely a [*BitwiseXORExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-BitwiseXORExpression) which can consist of solely a [*BitwiseANDExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-BitwiseANDExpression) which can consist of solely an [*EqualityExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-EqualityExpression) which can consist of solely a [*RelationalExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-RelationalExpression) which can consist of solely a [*ShiftExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-ShiftExpression) which can consist of solely an [*AdditiveExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-AdditiveExpression) which can consist of solely a [*MultiplicativeExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-MultiplicativeExpression) which can consist of solely an [*ExponentiationExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-ExponentiationExpression) which can consist of solely a [*UnaryExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-UnaryExpression) which can consist of solely an [*UpdateExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-update-expressions).

Which finally can consist of the [*LeftHandSideExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) that we were looking after.

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. But doesn't *UpdateExpression* require the increment or decrement operator to follow *LeftHandSideExpression*?

Comment: @Matthias No, just `LeftHandSideExpression` is the first of the five options there, so it doesn’t need those.

Comment: **12.4**  I see it now! Thank you, friends!

Comment: @Matthias Both the [*UpdateExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-UpdateExpression) rules in the ASI chapter and the *UpdateExpression* production in the [Annex](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-expressions) lack the rule that it can consist of solely a *LeftHandSideExpression*, but that appears to be an editorial mistake in the auto-generated annex. It will be fixed in [ES8](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-expressions) btw.

Comment: @Bergi Positive points to me for not being crazy, negative points for not being thorough. Really appreciate the follow-up info.