# How to properly read EcmaScript specification

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm interested in "HOW it work" knowledge for JavaScript binary logical operations, but I'm stuck at step interpritation.

So that's description of specs

> ### [12.13.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-LogicalANDExpression)
>
> *LogicalANDExpression: LogicalANDExpression **&&** BitwiseORExpression*
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be **? GetValue**(*lref*).
> 3. Let *lbool* be **ToBoolean**(*lval*).
> 4. If *lbool* is false, **return** *lval*.
> 5. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *BitwiseORExpression*.
> 6. **Return ? GetValue**(*rref*).

And i read this like:

1. Take memory for left operand and here will be operation result
2. Get value of left operand in memory and convert it to boolean
3. if this boolean is false, return left operand
4. Else take memory for right operand *and here will be...* ***BitwiseORExpression*** *<--* **what? Bitwise? for what? why?**

I'd would like to clarify this algorithm in more human-readable form for understanding how it works. What is p.1 and p.5, what really is *lref* and *rref*, what really is *LogicalANDExpression* and *BitwiseORExpression* in that context?

Comment: LogalANDExpression: `... && ...`, BitwiseORExpression: `... | ...`, For a description of BitwiseORExpression have a look at 12.12.x

Comment: Andreas, I'we seen this chapter, so i stuck at why and **how** BitwiseORExpression can be applied to single operand when it is binary operation and what effect of bitwise operations must affect right operand?Thanks!

Comment: Why "single operand"? 12.13.3 describes something like `if ((a === 1 && b === 2) && (a | b)) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*BitwiseORExpression* here just refers to the (expression for the) right operand, exactly like *LogicalANDExpression* refers to the left one as you correctly deduced. What it is depends on the code (or rather its parsed form, the AST) that you are currently evaluating, it could be [basically anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791592/1048572) and does not need to contain an `|` operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i read it (thanks to Bergi for the precisions):

1. create reference *lref* to store the result of the evaluation of the left operand expression *LogicalANDExpression*
2. create *lval* that gets the value of *lref* (evaluates it and throws an error if there is some)
3. create *lbool* that gets the boolean value corresponding to *lval*
4. if *lbool* is false, the whole operation will have the value *lval* and we stop here (that explains why `0 && 'foo'` gets `0` as result, and not `false`)
5. (if not stopped at precedent step) create reference *rref* to store the result of the evaluation of the right operand expression *BitwiseORExpression*
6. the whole operation will have the value of *rref* (still throws error if there is some. That explains why `1 && 'foo'` gets `'foo'` as result, and not `1` or `true`)

Comment: "*i assume there are things done with Types here*" - you can just check what [*GetValue*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-getvalue) does. Basically it evaluates property and identifier references.

Comment: @Bergi yes, i quickly read the definition, what i put in the brackets was more referring to the "?" sign just before this. It didn't seem necessary to go too deep into details here, but i will if asked to clarify

Comment: Oh, that. It's a [notational convention](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-algorithm-conventions) that basically says "break if this threw an exception".