# JavaScript - OR Operation with two false values

Tags: javascript

Related to coerce and default values in JavaScript, given this code:

```
function greet(name){
  name = name || '';
  console.log("Hello " + name);
}
greet();
```

Not given any name as parameter, we have

- undefined || ' '

And it's known that

- Boolean (undefined) coerces to false
- Boolean (' ') coerces to false

So we have:

false || false (undefined || ' ' )

Why the 'OR function' is returning the second parameter (' ') instead of the undefined if the undefined is first in the expression?

Comment: OR operator does not return boolean value. It returns first truthy value or last value. For more info, refer [Bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: you can [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47476337/7393478), it explains what's happening in detail