# Confusing on the syntax of ecmascript specification

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I am confusing on the following specification rules. Why is an "AdditiveExpression" should consist of another "AdditiveExpression" and  "MultiplicativeExpression"?

As the following rules say, we should evaluate the "AdditiveExpression" on the left side and the "MultiplicativeExpression" on the right side first, but what should the rule do if the right side of the operand is not the evaluating of "MultiplicativeExpression" but a "AdditiveExpression"?

[image: Ecmascript Specification]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Multiplication has a higher precedence.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax says the right operand of `+` *must* be a MultiplicativeExpression. If it isn't, you get a syntax error and nothing is evaluated.

For example, the expression `1 + 2 + 3` is parsed like this:

- `1` is a [`NumericLiteral`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-NumericLiteral), which is a [`Literal`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-Literal), which is a [`PrimaryExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-primary-expression).
- A `PrimaryExpression` is a [`MemberExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-MemberExpression), which is a [`NewExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-NewExpression), which is a [`LeftHandSideExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-LeftHandSideExpression), which is an [`UpdateExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-update-expressions), which is a [`UnaryExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-UnaryExpression), which is an [`ExponentiationExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ExponentiationExpression), which is a [`MultiplicativeExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-MultiplicativeExpression).
- A `MultiplicativeExpression` is an [`AdditiveExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-AdditiveExpression).
- `+` is ... `+`.
- `2` is a `NumericLiteral`, which is (by the chain listed above) a `MultiplicativeExpression`.
- At this point the rule `AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression` (quoted in your question) matches: `1 + 2` is parsed as an `AdditiveExpression`.
- We have another `+`, which is just `+`.
- `3` is a `NumericLiteral`, which is (by the chain listed above) a `MultiplicativeExpression`.
- Now `AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression` applies again (with `1 + 2` being the `AdditiveExpression` and `3` being the `MultiplicativeExpression`).
- The whole thing is now an `AdditiveExpression`.

Comment: @YHSPY Of a `+` without a MultiplicativeExpression on the right hand side? Sure, try `2 + )`. In Firefox I get `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'`.

Comment: what it will be parsed to If the expression is  "1 + 1 + 1" according to the rules?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the "AdditiveExpression" should consist of another "AdditiveExpression" and "MultiplicativeExpression"?

So that you can <s>nest</s> chain additive expression indefinitely: `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + …`

> what should the rule do if the right side of the operand is not the evaluating of "MultiplicativeExpression" but a "AdditiveExpression"?

That just doesn't happen. The expression `1 + 1 + 1` does parse as `(1 + 1) + 1` (where the right side *is* a MultiplicativeExpression), not as `1 + (1 + 1)`.

> The single number can be parsed as a "MultiplicativeExpression"?

Yes. The single number on the right side is a multiplicative expression, the single number on the lift side is an [addititive expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-additive-operators):

```
AdditiveExpression[Yield, Await]: MultiplicativeExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
```

that is also a [multiplicative expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-MultiplicativeExpression), which is an [ExponentiationExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-ExponentiationExpression), which is an [UnaryExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-UnaryExpression), which is a [UpdateExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-UpdateExpression) which is a [LeftHandSideExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression), which is a [NewExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-NewExpression), which is a [MemberExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-MemberExpression), which is a [PrimaryExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-PrimaryExpression), which is a [Literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-Literal), which consists of [NumericLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-NumericLiteral) lexem.

[This kind of nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791592/1048572) is how operator precedence is determined in the JS grammar.

Comment: You mean that the single number can be parsed as a "MultiplicativeExpression"? so, the expression "1 + 1 + 2 * 2" will be parsed to "(1 + 1) + (2 * 2)" like the rules say "AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression"?