# How can ECMAScript AssignmentExpression production rule produce `foo = 42`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, specifications, assignment-operator

As the [spec states](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13) (yes, 5.1, that's intentional):

```
AssignmentExpression :

    ConditionalExpression
    LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
    LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
```

Based on this definition, I don't understand how a simple `foo = 42` assignment is valid.

My understanding is, that `foo =` should always be followed by either a `ConditionalExpression` or essentially another assignment, but in that case, how will the production terminate if I don't use a `ConditionalExpression`? All further `AssignmentExpression` rules require either a `ConditionalExpression` or another `AssignmentExpression`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The [section right after that one](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) explains how exactly `foo = 42` is handled

Comment: Yes, you *should* use the `ConditionalExpression` rule. The literal `42` is a valid `ConditionalExpression` (as it is a valid `AssignmentExpression`), try tracing it down!

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the tip, you were right. Apparently, I did try tracing it down but stopped at `BitwiseXORExpression`, figuring I must be on the wrong track. :D

If you post an asnwer I am happy to accept it!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for the tip. Unfortunately that section does not explain how the production terminates, only how to _evaluate_ such an expression. Bergi gave the correct hint just after your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression after the `=` operator must always be an *AssignmentExpression*. This *AssignmentExpression* will often consist not of another assignment, but a plain *ConditionalExpression*, which in turn will consist of a simpler expression that might contain an operator or not, [all the way down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791592/1048572) through the operator precedence hierarchy to the *Literal* that your number `123` forms.