# What grammar is used for call expressions in EcmaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, language-lawyer, grammar

I'm trying to understand how grammars are defined in the EcmaScript spec a little better. However, I seem to be having a tough time to understand how the syntax for function calls are defined within the spec, take the following function invocation (assume `bar` has been defined already):

```js
const foo = 1;
bar(foo);
```

I'm specifically trying to find the grammar the allows for the `bar(foo);` syntax - I've tried using this great [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0cba6937212db26cf8c31e9e9757b31c/a5d07919eeb9223648714f044e71110b4719f20e) by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) and from that have found [*CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#prod-CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead) which is used by [*CallExpression*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-CallExpression):

> CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead[Yield, Await] :
>
> - MemberExpression<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> Arguments<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub>

So from my understanding, the identifier `bar` is the *MemberExpression* and `(foo)` is defined by the [*Arguments*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-Arguments) production rule, however, when looking at the production rule for *Arguments*, there seems to be nothing that allows for `(foo)` (a single idenfitier between `(` and `)`):

> Arguments<sub>[Yield, Await]</sub>:
>
> - ( )
> - ( ArgumentList<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> )
> - ( ArgumentList<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> , )
>
> ArgumentList<sub>[Yield, Await]:</sub>
>
> - AssignmentExpression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub>
> - ... AssignmentExpression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub>
> - ArgumentList<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> , AssignmentExpression<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub>
> - ArgumentList<sub>[?Yield, ?Await]</sub> , ... AssignmentExpression[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]

From what I can see, none of these cover the case where the argument list contains just one identifier `(foo)`, it covers other cases such as `(baz = 1)` (as baz=1 would be an *[AssignmentExpression](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-AssignmentExpression)* in this case)  etc... , but not one where there is a single identifier/literal passed into the function. Am I looking at the wrong production rule or am I not understanding something correctly here? Appologies if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: A list can have just one element in it ...

Comment: In other words, `foo` is a list of 1 argument.

Comment: Oh also note that `AssignmentExpression` does not *have* to be an assigment; the expression `3` is an assignment expression.

Comment: `foo` is a valid `AssignmentExpression`. It *can* also be `foo = 1`, but this is really just the  operator precedence level.

Comment: Any time the expression grammar is involved in some other production, it's necessary to start at or near the "top" of the grammar. Everything unwinds from there on down to the most basic expressions.

Comment: See also [ŧhis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62969339/1048572)

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense now, that was where my confusion was - thanks for clearing that up, I'll also take a look at the link provided :)

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that compared to many other languages, the JavaScript grammar is extremely complicated.

Comment: @Pointy - definitly, I've gotten lost with all the different production rules, it's great that the spec is detailed, but can be difficult to follow at times (thank for your tips though, that should help my in the future with navigating the grammars)